# jbpm 6 - Sample web application "rewards-basic" error

Tags: java, hibernate, jbpm, business-process-management

I am trying to run the jbpm6 sample web application "rewards-basic" in my local. But it seems two datasources files are missing.

```
<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.examples.rewards-basic" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/**JBPMorm.xml**</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/**Taskorm.xml**</mapping-file>
```

What for JBPMorm.xml and Taskorm.xml files ? How to recreate these files here ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

those files are in jbpm-human-task-jpa -> https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-jpa/src/main/resources/META-INF/Taskorm.xml

and

in jbpm-persistence-jpa:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-persistence-jpa/src/main/resources/META-INF/JBPMorm.xml

Notice that both files are in the main/src/resources directory so they should be included if you have jbpm-persistence-jpa.jar and jbpm-human-task-jpa in your class path.

HTH